# Scrape data middle of <b> and <br> tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is the HTML looks like:

```
<td>
        <font face="Arial, sans-serif" size="-1">

                    <b>Home Phone: </b>507-383-1070<br>

                    <b>Cell Phone: </b>507-383-1070<br>

                    <b>E-Mail: </b><a href=mailto:macehrhardt@gmail.com>macehrhardt@gmail.com</a><br>

        </font>
</td>
```

I just want to scrape data of `Home Phone` and `Cell Phone`, eg. `507-383-1070`. Can you please help me out this how I will use BeautifulSoup to solve this. I tried multiple methods but didn't find any way.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried already.

Comment: @sn3jd3r in the code I just got data between `<b>` tags not the numbers

Comment: Hint: use regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `soup.find_all` with a regular expression.

```
>>> soup.find_all(text=re.compile('\d+(-\d+){2}'))
['507-383-1070', '507-383-1070']
```

You might want to tweak your regex depending on the format of phone numbers you're trying to extract.

Comment: If I just want to scrape `Home Phone` then what should I do?

Comment: I can only post in 90 minutes. So can you give your answer here please?

Comment: @RageebArtho I can think of one solution involving `find_all` - find all `b` tags, compare the text to `Home Phone`, and if it matches, use `tag.nextSibling()` (or something of the sort - check the docs) and access its text attribute.

Comment: This is giving me `TypeError: 'NavigableString' object is not callable`

Comment: @RageebArtho Sorry, can't debug your code if I can't see it. Just wait a bit more, post a new question, and link me to it. Cheers.

Comment: @RageebArtho Fantastic, glad to hear.

Answer (score 0):

For the HTML you have given, they could be extracted as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<td>
        <font face="Arial, sans-serif" size="-1">
                    <b>Home Phone: </b>507-383-1070<br>
                    <b>Cell Phone: </b>507-383-1070<br>
                    <b>E-Mail: </b><a href=mailto:macehrhardt@gmail.com>macehrhardt@gmail.com</a><br>
        </font>
</td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
entries = [b.next.next for b in soup.find_all('b')][:2]

print entries
```

Giving you:

```
[u'507-383-1070', u'507-383-1070']
```